# Can I have extra minecraft inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can I have extra Minecraft inventory in vanilla Minecraft?  I have seen mods be able to do this but never in vanilla Minecraft.  Is there some way for me to carry more.  Maybe  a command that allows me to carry more than a stack of 64 or have more slots to carry more.  I cannot figure this out, if there even is away.

Comment: Are you surviving or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shulker Boxes deserve a dedicated answer of their own.

---

It is now possible to have extra inventory slots (as of 1.11).

You simply need a [Shulker Box](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker_Box)...

- 27 item slots
- can be placed and broken
- **they *keep* their inventory when broken**, so you can access it after placing the box again
- can be placed in your inventory and other containers
- *cannot* be placed in other Shulker Boxes
- unlike chests the Shulker Box will be facing away from the block it's placed against
- you can give it a name using an Anvil.

Comment: For anyone playing Survival, Shulker Boxes are a very end-game item (one of the last items in the game you'll be able to craft), so for the vast majority of a survival game for most players they are unattainable.  If you are playing creative mode you don't need inventory as you can just spawn whatever you want whenever you want.  

Answer (score 14):

There is no way in vanilla Minecraft to expand your inventory, whether by commands or by other means.

If you wish to have a larger inventory, you could try making an [Ender Chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest) and using one slot of your inventory to carry it around. Note that you need a silk touch pick in order to pick it back up.

This would mean you can have up to 61 inventory slots (63 minus two slots to carry the Ender Chest and pick) and 4 armour slots total. This is 25 more than the normal 36 slots.

Comment: To use the Ender Chest as a backpack of sorts, you will need a Pickaxe with Silk Touch. This requirement removes one more slot, or you'd have to carry multiple Ender Chests which may be become pretty expensive.

Comment: @Thorsal Good point. I have edited my answer to contain this info.

Comment: You could also take a mule.

Comment: Ore take a stack of eyes of ender. But who's got time for that...

Comment: You should put in shulker boxes as well. You can break shulker boxes and they will keep their items.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that there is a way to have more room in *your **own** inventory.*
Instead, there are other ways to carry more:

1. Build a "donkey train". **Attach chests to some donkeys (or mules), mount one of them, then *use a lead* to pull the others with you.** With this method, you can significantly increase your storage slots, with *15 per donkey*.
2. Use Ender Chests. They act like "cloud storage", meaning that the items you put in one, can also be picked up from another one that's far, far away. Furthermore, what you store in them **is private**, giving you a **world-wide storage available only for you**, increasing your storage slots *by 27*.
3. Use Shulker Boxes. They condense a whole chest's worth of storage into one block that cannot be stacked, but can be placed down and picked back up with any tool without dropping their contents.
4. Carry your items in "packed" states, like:

   - **Blocks of ore** instead of **materials (ores)**
   - **Bones** instead of **bone meal**
   - **Logs** instead of **planks**
   - Etc.

   This method may help you to *preserve your already existing* slots. Sometimes it may help you to make **massive slot savings**, or sometimes it may be **insignificant**.

Answer (score 0):

Fill your inventory with shulker boxes full of 64 stack items, then, in your off-hand, hold an ender chest full of 27 shulker boxes with 27 stacks of 64 stack items, and wear armor for max item storage.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how things work around here. Your solutions has already been provided in the other answers, so if you have a new solution that has not already been covered, you can include it to improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a way to increase your **OWN** Inv, but ender chests and shulker boxes would be a way to have more storage

Comment: Hi! Both options have already been suggested in the existing answers. Please don't duplicate information. I suggest taking the [Tour]. Welcome to Arqade!